# Rails 4 can't find images with filename in specific format

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

The issue:
When I try to include an image on a page and the image has the following filename format, Rails returns a 404 and can't find the image:

2014-08-13-abcdef1.png

Making it a bit more strange, if I remove that last "1", it finds the image correctly.
Also, if I replace the "1" with something that's not in the hex alphabet (like "g") it finds the image correctly.

Does Rails have an issue with seven-character hex strings in asset file names???
Anyone have a similar issue, or know how to resolve this?
Renaming all of the image files (there are hundreds) isn't really an option.
I have tried disabling the asset pipeline but the problem persists (and keep the pipeline disabled isn't really a good fix anyway).

Comment: When you use an `image_tag` with such a filename, what URL does the image get in the resulting HTML source of the webpage?

Comment: I tried to used the image filename(which you got some error) and upload it using Rails code, but it's properly rendered in my code. I'm also using Rails 4 (4.2.0 to be exact).
My code is simply like image_tag(@user.first.image.url(:original)).
Which generate the html of: <img src="/images/users/1/medium/2014-08-13-abcdef1.png" alt="2014 08 13 abcdef1">

Comment: I was able to use the absolute path as a workaround for now - if I come up with a solution I'll report back - thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

I'm can not be sure, but i can suppose, that `image_tag` will help you.

Rails supports long file names without any problems.

Comment: Sadly image_tag gives the same behavior.  In this case it's not an issue of filename length - files with longer names are being successfully picked up in the asset pipeline.  
It looks like something goes screwy because it's a Hex string...length doesn't seem to matter.